# what failure can cause a new fridge *fan* to run all the time?

Tags: appliances

We recently bought a "beverage center fridge": https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAEuB.jpg

It is brand new. It has been running for a week. It is nice and cold and the condensor seems to be operating as normal: on and off (it is not constantly on). However, the fans under the unit that blow across the condensor *never* shut off and they are loud. My kitchen sounds like a wind tunnel. My understanding is that these fans should only be on when the condensor turns on.

So my question is, what can cause this failure? This is brand new (no dust or dirtiness), and the condensor is operating on/off as normal, so I didn't think it was the thermostat. So what part can be broken that triggers these fans to be on all the time?

I could live with the noise of these fans if they were on a small portion of the time when the condensor is on, however I'm returning it if this is "by design".

EDIT: model: https://www.wayfair.com/Maxx-Ice-3-Cu.-Ft.-Indoor-Refrigerator-MAXX1010.html

Manual: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ps7on4qvs1dnz1u/73491f5e-38d0-4412-9a89-32b7ad05d5d1.pdf?dl=0

The manual has a wiring diagram but I'm not an electrician and don't know what to make of it. Here's a pic of that diagram: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIpCt.jpg

Comment: You should edit into your question the make and exact model number.

Comment: @Tyson I thought that would make my question too specific to receive answers, and thought this might be a general problem with refrigerators.

Comment: No, it sounds like a problem that we'll need make and model to fix...

Comment: Nope... this problem is pretty specific to the make/model you purchased.... if it's working correctly.  We don't know until you say which make/model has this problem

Comment: OK I've added that info

Comment: How are you determining that the compressor is turning on or off if the fans are loud. Generally the only way to know if the compressor is working is the hear it cycle on and off. On some older units you can feel the fridge shake a little when the compressor shuts down.

Comment: I opened up the back panel, and I turn the cold settings knob to "coldest" and I can hear the compresser turn on. A new "humming" sound starts and I can see a big black thing start vibrating, and inside the fridge a fan starts. When I turn the cold settings knob to "OFF", that humming sound stops and the fan inside the fridge turns off.

Comment: i tried to download the pdf from the manufacturer and adobe reader could not open it. here is the contact for them  Phone: (954) 202-7419
Fax Icon Fax: (954) 202-7337
Email Icon Email: info@maxxcoldfoodservice.com

Comment: @Alaskaman here is a picture of wiring diagram: http://imgur.com/a/V9yTE

Comment: I am not an appliance technician or electrician so i will have to defer to someone with knowledge of appliance wiring. When it was transported to the house was it laid on its side or tipped significantly and then subsequently plugged in to power right away. If so then the fluid in the compressor  would not have had a chance to settle and damage could have occurred that would be telling the fans they need to be on.  Try unplugging it and letting it sit for a day or two.

Answer (score 1):

> **what can cause this failure?**

The unit has two fans, a "condenser fan" and an "evaporator fan"

The condenser fan should come on only when the temperature drops below the temperature set by the thermostat.

It looks like it is designed for an "evaporator fan" to be running continuously when the door is shut

[image]

Power goes to the lamp (presumably when the door is open) or to the evaporator fan (when the door is closed).

So the answer depends on whether what you are hearing is the evaporator fan or the condenser fan.

Either way, it is a new unit and either faulty or not suited for your intended purpose - so I'd take it back for a refund.

Comment: ... what happens if I were to remove or maybe swap out that fan for a less noisy one?

Comment: All the same, it's quite possible that the Evap fan is defective & generating far more noise than it should, or (less likely) the owner has very high AC voltage and the fan's being overdriven.   Granted, I'm an experienced hacker, but I would try checking the connections to the motor to make sure there's no "Hi-tap" post that shouldn't have been used.  (Then again, I'd never buy anything from Wayfair...)